# Unable to access variables true content. Value always stays null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem with providing variables. I have those two variables contentname and contentbirthday which are in a onchanged as you can see below:

```
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/card_data.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'constants.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/card_data.dart';

class CardBasic extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardBasicState createState() => _CardBasicState();
}

class _CardBasicState extends State<CardBasic> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
          0.58, //<-- set height of the card
      child: FirstCardCreation(
        //<-- new widget
        name: 'Name',
        birthday: ' Birthday',
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstCardCreation extends StatelessWidget {
  final String name;
  final String birthday;

  const FirstCardCreation({
    Key key,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.birthday,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Color(0xFFef9a9a),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      elevation: 8,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32)),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 8),
          Expanded(
            child:
                FirstCardContent(contentname: name, contentbirthday: birthday),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstCardContent extends StatelessWidget {
  String contentname;
  String contentbirthday;

  FirstCardContent(
      {Key key, @required this.contentname, @required this.contentbirthday})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: kNameInput,
              onChanged: (value1) {
                print(contentname);
                contentname = value1;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: kBirthdayInput,
              onChanged: (value2) {
                contentbirthday = value2;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have created a Provider in my main.dart, so that I can pass the information of those two variables to another class. In the class where I want to use them, I created a Consumer. On the Finish Button right at the bottom, I want to use the two variables, but the value is null. Does anyone know how I can access the variables information correctly?

```
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/real_new_algorithm_card.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Components/custom_Buttons.dart';
import 'new_card_screen1.dart';
import '../Components/constants.dart';
import '../Components/real_new_algorithm_card.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/card_data.dart';
import 'package:biminda_app/Components/real_new_card.dart';

class AlgorithmInput extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'new_algorithm_screen';
  @override
  _AlgorithmInputState createState() => _AlgorithmInputState();
}

class _AlgorithmInputState extends State<AlgorithmInput> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<FirstCardContent>(
        builder: (context, firstCardContent, child) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
                child: Text('Feed the algorithm.', style: kBackgroundTextStyle),
              ),
              CardBasicAlgorithm(),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SideButton(
                        functionality: 'Back',
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, NewCard.id);
                        }),
                    SideButton(
                        // TODO: Beim drücken auf den Button muss der vorherige und
                        // TODO: neue Input mitgenommen werden und in die neue Card
                        // TODO: eingetragen werden
                        functionality: 'Finish',
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
                          Provider.of<CardData>(context).addCard(
                              firstCardContent.contentname,
                              firstCardContent.contentbirthday);
                          //print(firstCardContent.contentname);
                          //print(firstCardContent.contentbirthday);
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

For explanation: The App wants the user to enter data (contentname and contentbirthday), which gets passed to a Listview.builder after pressing the finish button. I have created two print statements inside the onPressed to see if the values are correct. Unfortunately I only get the values null.

Please ignore the german written TODO'S.

Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing **FirstCardContent** to a StatefulWidget as you will be needing *setState*

Like this

```
class FirstCardContent extends StatefulWidget {
  String contentname;
  String contentbirthday;

  FirstCardContent(
      {Key key, @required this.contentname, @required this.contentbirthday})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstCardContentState createState() => _FirstCardContentState();
}

class _FirstCardContentState extends State<FirstCardContent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: kNameInput,
              onChanged: (value1) {
                setState(() {
                print(widget.contentname);
                  widget.contentname = value1;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: TextField(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: kBirthdayInput,
              onChanged: (value2) {
                setState(() {
                  widget.contentbirthday = value2;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer my friend. Sadly, the print statement still says null for both variables. But a great approach. I didn't thought about this.

Comment: Oh I see... That is because of the print wasn't inside setState

Comment: Check it out now

Comment: The print statements inside the onchanged are working. But if I want to use it inside the Provider right at the bottom of _AlgorithmInputState the value is still null. 

Thank you so much for your fast and precise answers.

Comment: It wouldn't fit in here, but I would be so grateful if you could take a look into my whole code.

Comment: I will find a solution.

Comment: Oh Ok...Goodluck

Comment: Oh great...would check it out